# Azure release pipeline variable with dot appsettings.json

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-releases

I got stuck with this setup on Azure release variable using the classic setting.
With .net i can assign the value like
I tried below and it didn't work.
'AppNamespace1.Domain1.Category1.Configuration'.Endpoints.ProcessorEndpoint.EndpointURL
and
AppNamespace1.Domain1.Category1.Configuration.Endpoints.ProcessorEndpoint.EndpointURL

My appsettings.json look like this and I am not allowed to change "AppNamespace1.Domain1.Category1.Configuration".

appsettings.json

```
{
  "AppNamespace1.Domain1.Category1.Configuration": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "ProcessorEndpoint": {
        "EndpointURL": "http://localhost:50576/RequestExecutor/",
        "ClientKey": "DefaultClient"
      },
     
  }
}
```

Expected result

"EndpointURL": "NEW VALUE HERE"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a sample to update the value of **`EndpointURL`** in the **`appsettings.json`** file.

You can try to run the PowerShell script mentioned here in your pipeline.

- **`appsettings.json`**

```json
{
    "AppNamespace1.Domain1.Category1.Configuration": {
        "Endpoints": {
            "ProcessorEndpoint": {
                "EndpointURL": "http://the/old/url/",
                "ClientKey": "DefaultClient"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- **`update-json.ps1`**: PowerShell script to update the JSON file.

```
$newURL = "http://the/new/url/"

# Read the content of appsettings.json file.
Write-Host "Read the content of appsettings.json file."
$jsonContent =  Get-Content .\appsettings.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
Write-Host ($jsonContent | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)

# Get the old EndpointURL.
Write-Host "Get the old EndpointURL."
$oldURL = $jsonContent.'AppNamespace1.Domain1.Category1.Configuration'.Endpoints.ProcessorEndpoint.EndpointURL
Write-Host $oldURL

Write-Host "=============================================="

# Update the EndpointURL to the new one.
Write-Host "Update the EndpointURL to the new one."
$jsonContent.'AppNamespace1.Domain1.Category1.Configuration'.Endpoints.ProcessorEndpoint.EndpointURL = $newURL
$jsonContent | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 | Out-File .\appsettings.json  

Write-Host "=============================================="

# Read the content of appsettings.json file after updating the EndpointURL.
Write-Host "Read the new content of appsettings.json file."
$jsonContentNew =  Get-Content .\appsettings.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
Write-Host ($jsonContentNew | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)

# Get the new EndpointURL.
Write-Host "Get the new EndpointURL."
$readNewURL = $jsonContentNew.'AppNamespace1.Domain1.Category1.Configuration'.Endpoints.ProcessorEndpoint.EndpointURL
Write-Host $readNewURL
```

- **Result**

  [image]

Comment: Cool thank  you, i really appreciate your expertise